# Grouping or batching messages by id in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, kotlin, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I've created queue for multiple consumers on one client. I send message as `Pair<String, String>` - first string is ID, second is a message itself. I want to group messages by first string.

```
@RabbitListener(queues = ["\${app.rabbitmq.queuename:test}"])
fun receiveBatch(messages: List<Pair<String, String>>) {
    val groupedMessages = messages.asSequence()
        .groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second })
        .mapValues { it.value.fold("") { acc, s -> groupFrameMessages(acc, s) } }
        .also { log.debug { "Grouped messages contains Ids: ${it.keys}}" } }
        .toList()

    groupMessages.forEach{ "Handle $it" }
}
```

In order to handle concurrency, I require to have only one consumer per message Id, since there's a heavy operation to handle the message, which completely interrupts if the second consumer tries to connect, leading to data loss. The current solution is a lockMap:

```
val lockMap = ConcurrentHashMap<String, Lock>()
```

It will not work if I will have more than one instance connected. I have to do two things - first is implementing distributed lock or, a better solution, limit concurrent consumers of messages with that id to 1; second is group those messages by id somehow. How can I do it? Is there any way to group messages by that id? Is there a way to create dynamic queues by id?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; it would be simplest to use a different queue for each id and have only one consumer for each queue.

You can use the `RabbitAdmin` to create queues and bindings dynamically and you can add/remove queues to the listener container as needed. It's best to use a `DirectMessageListenerContainer` for this - see [Choosing a Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#choose-container).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. But I can't actually find ways to connect to those dynamic queues and how to use those containers properly. Can you please give me a link with examples, please?

Comment: I don't have examples, but it's pretty straightforward; you could use a control queue - with all consumers consuming from it; when a new queue is added, one of the consumers can pick it up and add the new queue to its listener container.